# What is the role of the subscript $z$ in "$\log\dfrac{x}{z^9}$"?

Tags: logarithms

I was doing my trigonometry readiness assessment for a class when this question popped up. I tried searching a description of the z's placement but I couldn't find anything that seemed right. It doesn't look like it's in the right place to be the base. I would like to know what it is, and what I'm supposed to do with it for the next time it comes up. Is it possibly a typo?

[image: math equation with potentially questionable typesetting]

Comment: It looks to me like $$\log\frac{x}{\;z^9\;}$$that is, $x$ divided by the ninth power of $z$.

Answer (score 1):

My assumption is it is meant to read

$$\log \left( \frac{x}{z^9} \right) \text{ or equivalently } \log \left( x \cdot z^{-9} \right)$$

with no base stated. (What that means for the base of the logarithm depends on context. Sometimes $\log(x)$ with no base means $\log_e(x), \log_{10}(x),$ or even $\log_2(x)$, depending on the field you're working in. Use whatever convention is most relevant for your class.)